# I want to get all child of child items one by one in firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**here is model class :**

**I want that I get all food items from all categories one by one and
than show every single food item data in recycler view**

**and after getting list of all items I want that I add only those items in a list which pin value is TRUE**

```
public class Items {
    String name, desc,image, category;
    int price;
    boolean pin;


    public Items(String name, String desc, String image, String category, int price, boolean pin) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
        this.category = category;
        this.price = price;
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public Items() {
    }

    public boolean isPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(boolean pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

**here is the java class file code :**
*when I check snapshot using snapshot.getValue() in log it gives me all categories also items, but it is not adding in a list...why ???*

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                list.getClass();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                    Items items = dataSnapshot.getValue(Items.class);
                    list.add(items);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

**this is my database :**

[image: I want all food item from all category one by one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){` loop only loops over one level in the database, so your `dataSnapshot` points to `BBQ` and then `Chines`, not to the individual food items.

Since you want to loop over two nested node levels, you need two nested loops in your code:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("admin");
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        list.getClass();
        for (DataSnapshot categorySnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){ // 
            for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot : categorySnapshot.getChildren()){ // 
                Items items = itemSnapshot.getValue(Items.class); // 
                list.add(items);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); //  Never ignore errors
    }
});
```